# List files of particular type from a specific directory

Tags: file, unix

How to list particular type of files from a specific directory? e.g. I want to list all *.csv files from /home/ABC/files/ directory and I am in /home directory right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[TMTOWTDI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt).

```
(cd /home/ABC/files/; ls *.csv)
ls /home/ABC/files/*.csv | sed 's:.*/::'
ls /home/ABC/files/*.csv | xargs -n1 basename
ls /home/ABC/files/*.csv | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
for i in /home/ABC/files/*.csv; do echo "${i##*/}"; done
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind `${f##*/}` in the last line? Or point towards some reading material to understand it? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

```
ls ABC/files/*.csv
ls /home/ABC/files/*.csv
echo ABC/files/*.csv
echo /home/ABC/files/*.csv
```

using for loop

```
for file in ABC/files/*.csv
do
   # further processing
done
```

and of course, the ever useful find.(GNU)

```
find ABC/file -type f -iname "*.csv" -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: The command you told about "find" gives the name of files from subdirectories also which I don't want.

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1` to be consistent?

Answer (score 3):

```
ls ABC/files/*.csv
ls /home/ABC/files/*.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I just want file name and not full path. It list /home/ABC/files/test1.csv, /home/ABC/files/test2.csv , while I just want file names like test1.csv and test2.csv